'socket.http' module isn't found when using require
So I am trying to make a lua script that use "socket.http" but it seems to be missing some dlls or .lua and i'm trying to understand how I would be able to add them into the same folder as my let's call it executor. This is what i get when i try "local socket = require("socket.http").
screenshot:

I have already downloaded the src for socket.http from luasocket repository but i don't know what to do after like
where do i add the files in the folder of my executable, so that I could be able to use socket.http?
I've tried just adding the src folder to the path where my "executor" is and that didn't work for some reason, i also tried adding a folder called "lua" with only socket.lua and http.lua but that yet again didn't work too.

The error message lists several "no file" entries.  You should put your file at one of these locations to make require() find it.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
